Are questions about developing my own Ghidra modules on-topic here?
I'm currently playing with making some Loader and Filesystem modules for Ghidra for 8-bit computers. (I'm not very good at it so don't get excited.)
Ghidra comes with extensions to Eclipse to aid in this endeavor. Eclipse is a Java IDE. I've been a (mostly hobby) programmer for 40 years but I always avoided Java.
So while I am 100% sure questions in this arena would be on-topic on Stack Overflow, they might miss most of their target audience compared to here, and it's very common for a question to be on-topic on two or even more SE sites. They may or may not also be within the scope of the Retrocomputing SE site, but I tend to think they wouldn't be welcome there if they were mostly about Java or Ghidra rather than say the retro machine file formats.
Since both Java and Eclipse are huge it would take me a long time to learn both from the ground up. I prefer hands-on learning as I go, but that means newbie questions arise, which are not always embraced on SO.
But moreover, in the case of Ghidra, the documentation is limited and while there are tutorials for using Ghidra, there are not many for Java modules. There's maybe two for loaders, and none for filesystems. So I can only learn by looking at the existing module source code and by experimentation.
So, given the above, would questions about Ghidra-specific programming problems I run into be on-topic and welcome here? I don't intend to ask generic Java- or Eclipse-related programming questions here of course.

I think if you stick to the plan from your last paragraph, it should be fine:

Java or Eclipse related → Stackoverflow
Ghidra → RE.SE

... but let's see what the community and other moderators have to say.
Either way, my take on this is that developing something for an RE tool is on-topic as long as it's not a generic programming question that would be better suited for Stackoverflow. No one would argue, for example, that idapro-sdk or idapython or ida-plugin are on-topic here.
